# Is there a way to cycle options in C++/GLUT

Tags: c++, glut

I am making a program that will cycle the color of a triangle with the up and down arrows.  I am pretty new to GLUT and C++, so I can't figure out a way to "cycle" colors.

Here is the triangle code:

void render(void) {

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(      0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glColor3f(red, green, blue);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-2, 0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(2, 0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(2, 2, 0.0);

glEnd();

angle+=0.1f;

glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

and the input code:

void processSpecialKey(int key, int x, int y) {

```
switch(key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP :
                    red += 1.0;
                    green += 0.0;
                    blue += 0.0; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN :
                    red += 0.0;
                    green += 1.0;
                    blue += 0.0; break;
}
```

}

Comment: There's a bazillion ways to do opengl, from immediate mode to vbo's to shaders.  It would help if you showed us whatever code you've written so far.  "cycling" colors could mean almost anything, so you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry! im really new to stack overflow.  here is code for my triangle and switch for the colors.  I just dont know a way to make the color values switch between different colors as i press the arrows.